# How to copy and paste filtered power pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, copy-paste, powerpivot

Could you please help me with below problem statement, 
I want to copy and paste a power pivot table from one sheet to other. 
Problem here is this table is filtered with some specific values like country, business etc. I don't want the other data to be visible. 
I just want to copy and paste the values in table which is visible. 
I am able to select the table using ctrl+a and the paste as values and format. 
But the colour in table header and in grand total does not appear. 
Could you please help me so that i could paste the table with exact color in header and grand total. 
Or if there is any other way to do so.

Comment: @Alexis Olson Thanks for your reply. I tried using cliboard but the values in pivot tables does not appear. It just shows zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting from the Office Clipboard.

[image: Screenshot]